# Java JPA @ManyToMany relation using mySQL empty join table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, join, many-to-many

I am working on an app that downloads job offers from different online services in JSON then parsing it into my own Offer class and puts parsed data into mySql database. My Offer class has field Set<Skill> skills which has String name field according to the name of skill.There is ManyToMany relation between offer and skill and the result is joining table offer_skill_set. While mapping downloaded JSON into my Offer class using SkillRepository i check if the skill already exist in db and if yes, I'm getting it or saving it to db if there was no skill with this name. There is no errors in logs, downloading, parsing and saving to db works fine, there are no duplicated skills in Skill table, and offers are properly. The problem is, that the offer_skill_set is empty. I've tried with different cascadeTypes, but no results.

Skill class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor


@Entity
@Table(name = "skill")
public class Skill {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
)
@JoinTable(
        name="offer_skill_set",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="skill_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="offer_id"),
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "skill_id", "offer_id" })
)
private Set<Offer> offerSkillSet = new HashSet<>();
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,
        mappedBy = "skillPreferences")
private Set<UserPreferences> userPreferencesSkillSet = new HashSet<>();

public Skill(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Offer class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Offer {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long offerId;

private String companyName;

private boolean isRemoteWork;
@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "salary_id")
private OfferSalary offerSalary;
private String location;
private String url;
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,
        mappedBy = "offerSkillSet")
private Set<Skill> skillSet = new HashSet<>();
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "offerPreferences")
private Set<UserPreferences> userPreferencesSet = new HashSet<>();



public Offer(String companyName, boolean isRemoteWork,
OfferSalary offerSalary, String location,    Set<Skill> skillSet, String url) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.isRemoteWork = isRemoteWork;
    this.offerSalary = offerSalary;
    this.location = location;
    this.skillSet = skillSet;
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

Mapping service for one json(other are commented out for testing):

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JustJoinItDownloader implements JobDownloader {
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
private final SkillRepository skillRepository;

@Value("${downloader.justjoinit.url}")
private String url;

@Override
public List<Offer> map(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
    List<JustJoinItRootPojo> jjitOffers =
            Arrays.stream(objectMapper.readValue(json, JustJoinItRootPojo[].class)).toList();
    int size = jjitOffers.size();
    List<Offer> offerListJjit = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 1;
    for (JustJoinItRootPojo justJoinItRootPojo : jjitOffers) {
        System.out.println("mapowanie jjit: " + counter++ + "/" + size);
        for (OfferSalary offerSalary : getSalaryAndTypeOfContractJjit(justJoinItRootPojo)) {
            offerListJjit
   .add(new Offer(justJoinItRootPojo.getCompany_name(),   justJoinItRootPojo.isRemote(),
                    offerSalary, justJoinItRootPojo.getCity(),
                    getSkillSetJjit(justJoinItRootPojo.getSkills().
                            stream()
   .map(Skill::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet())), justJoinItRootPojo.getCompany_url()));

        }
    }
    return offerListJjit;
}

@Override
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

private List<OfferSalary> getSalaryAndTypeOfContractJjit(JustJoinItRootPojo justJoinItRootPojo)              {
    return    justJoinItRootPojo.getEmployment_types()
   .stream().map(OfferSalary::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

 private Set<Offer.Skill>       getSkillSetJjit(Set<String> skills) {
    Set<Offer.Skill> skillSet = new HashSet<>  ();
    for (String skill : skills) {
        Optional<Offer.Skill> skillByName 
         =   skillRepository.findByName(skill);
        if (skillByName.isPresent()) {
            skillSet.add(skillByName.get());
        } else {
            skillSet
            .add(Offer.Skill(skill));
            skillRepository
      .saveAndFlush(new Offer.Skill(skill));
        }
    }
    return skillSet;
}
}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestingController {
private final OfferService offerService;
private final OfferRepository offerRepository;

@GetMapping("/offer-download-save")
public ResponseEntity testMethod() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        offerService.saveOffersToDb();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Offer service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OfferService {
private final OfferServiceFacade offerServiceFacade;
private final ExecutorService executorService;
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
private final OfferRepository offerRepository;
private final MailService mailService;
private final UserRepository userRepository;




@Transactional
public void saveOffersToDb() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<Offer> offers = getALlOffers();
    offerRepository.saveAllAndFlush(offers);
}
private List<Offer> getALlOffers() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Future<List<Offer>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    List<JobDownloader> allDownloaders = offerServiceFacade.getAllDownloaders();
    for (JobDownloader allDownloader : allDownloaders) {
      Future<List<Offer>> submit = executorService
        .submit(new JobOfferTask(allDownloader,            restTemplate));
        futures.add(submit);
    }
    for (Future<List<Offer>> future : futures) {
        List<Offer> c = future.get();
        offers.addAll(c);
    }
    return offers;
 }
}
```

How to set the relation or update the code to get proper relation on `offer_skill_set`?

Comment: That is a lot of code to go through, but the offer_skill_set table is controlled by the skill.offerSkillSet mapping/references. If that set is empty, nothing will get added to the table. If you want to add to that table by just adding new Offers, reverse the mapping; define the join table/reference in the Offers entity and have the Skills mapping change to be mappedBy skillSet

Comment: reversed mapping worked. Thank You very much